# How to change android version Jellybean 4.2.2 to the newest update?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4, 5.1-lollipop, android-versions

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 Zoom and my current Android version is Jelly Bean 4.2.2. I kept on trying to update the version but it kept on saying that my phone has installed the newest update. How can I change my Android version to the Lollipop one?

Comment: Samsung hasn't announced any lollipop update for S4 zoom

Answer (score 2):

Accorrding to [GSM ARENA](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s4_zoom-5447.php) your phone officially supports an upgrade to 4.4.2 Kitkat. However you can try a custom ROM for your phone. Read more about rooting and recoveries(Google is your friend)

As to why it is not updating to 4.4.3, maybe this will clear things out [XDA-devs s4 zoom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-zoom/general/s4-zoom-kitkat-update-custom-recovery-t2820281)

Answer (score 2):

You can't just automatically "change" your version to Lollipop or Kitkat. Either Samsung needs to send an update to your phone, or your carrier (eg. Verizon, Sprint) needs to send the update to your phone. Otherwise you're stuck with 4.2.2.

If you want the latest version of Android, you'll need to install a custom version like Cyanogenmod: http://www.cyanogenmod.org/

You can post additional questions if you need help unlocking/rooting/installing Cyanogenmod.